# Youtube javascript most popular videos API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to implement Youtube's most popular videos api in my application.

When I fetch data using ajax call, it is missing the **"rel": "next"** tag which is very important in identifying whether there are more videos or not. **"openSearch$totalResults"** also does not give any reliable information.

I have read the documentation and they have not mentioned anything related to how many total results will this API return.

My ajax call URL format is as under :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?start-index='+StartIndex+'&max-results='+EndIndex+'&time=all_time&safeSearch=none&orderby=published&v=2&alt=json&callback=?

Can somebody please help me and tell me whether I am making some mistake or their is some other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[YouTube's most popular videos feed is changed](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2013/09/what-to-watch-our-apis-can-help_12.html).

[Right now the best way is to use Data API v3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcrG0_XTO9o&feature=youtu.be).