# How to get the list of most popular italian youtube channels in JSON format with api?

Tags: url, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would take the list of the most popular Italian youtube channels in this format https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels. I have a API key. I should search for snippet.country attribute? What is the URL to use?
Thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) documentation. Use the `mostPopular` parameter which returns the most popular videos for the specified [content region](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#regionCode) and [video category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#videoCategoryId).

Here are some references:

- [youtube-most-popular](https://github.com/ryandao/youtube-most-popular)
- [Youtube javascript most popular videos API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094060/youtube-javascript-most-popular-videos-api)